# Unexported kernel api usage in module

Tags: api, kernel

Im trying to use irq_to_desc api to obtain the chip data and to set the irq affinity from kernel module. But the api irq_to_desc is not exported in linux kernel.
Is there any way through which I can obtain the irq chip data or set irq_affinity through any other means?

Thanks,
dev

Comment: In current kernel version `irq_to_desc` is exported for modules. What version of the kernel you use?

Comment: Im using 2.6.32 kernel.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that kernel 2.6.32 doesn't provide access to irq descriptors for modules. All drivers which use it are compiled as built-in.

If you really need this function, you can use `find_symbol` for get its address:

```
// It will be pointer to irq_to_desc function.
struct irq_desc (*func_irq_to_desc)(unsigned int irq); 

// Initialize pointer to function
struct kernel_symbol* ks = find_symbol("irq_to_desc");
if(ks)
  func_irq_to_desc = (typeof(func_irq_to_desc))ks->value;

// Use function
func_irq_to_desc(2)->affinity = 3;
```

Of course, this is a hack. Also, using `find_symbol` requires "GPL" license of the module.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this.